# How does one style large dynamic text strings in Angular?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, html

I've currently using the HomeAway API, that returns an important property I must include in my app.  It is a description, which gives key details about the rental listing the user will be seeing.

**The challenge:**  This description gets sent as one large block of text.

This block has various details that really must be separated visually and stylized to make it readable.

**My question:**  Is there any elegant way to stylize potentially large blocks of dynamic text?

---

## Example

*The text gets returned like this (significantly shortened for sanity):*

Your ultra-modern smart home promises absolute luxury in the heart of Hollywood. A spacious three-story layout includes a glass-encased spiral staircase and a classy backyard with a hot tub and privacy curtains. ABOUT THE HOUSE A cool mid-century vibe delights in the open-concept living room, where a couch and two armchairs offset vibrant white walls. Control everything from the lights to the blinds from a tablet in both bedrooms. Extras at the home include a stainless steel washer/dryer set and complimentary Wi-Fi. Parking is available on the street. The home next door is also available to accommodate larger parties. THE LOCATION Walking distance to Larchmont Village and a quick drive from all the classic Hollywood attractions, this unique home is right where you want to be. Fuel up with vegetarian fare and fresh juices at Cafe Gratitude in less than 1 block. A few steps away, Osteria Mamma is the delicious Italian eatery and wine bar you're seeking for a romantic dinner. WHAT TO EXPECT FROM A PROPERTY MANAGED BY TURNKEY VACATION RENTALS TurnKey Vacation Rentals is a leading full-service property management company. We guarantee all listing information is accurate and up to date. From the moment you book, you’ll be provided timely and helpful communications regarding your trip. Upon arrival, easily access your unit with a keyless secure door code; no need for an in-person key exchange.

## Ideally

Your ultra-modern smart home promises absolute luxury in the heart of Hollywood. A spacious three-story layout includes a glass-encased spiral staircase and a classy backyard with a hot tub and privacy curtains.

*ABOUT THE HOUSE*

A cool mid-century vibe delights in the open-concept living room, where a couch and two armchairs offset vibrant white walls. Control everything from the lights to the blinds from a tablet in both bedrooms. Extras at the home include a stainless steel washer/dryer set and complimentary Wi-Fi. Parking is available on the street. The home next door is also available to accommodate larger parties.

*THE LOCATION*

Walking distance to Larchmont Village and a quick drive from all the classic Hollywood attractions, this unique home is right where you want to be. Fuel up with vegetarian fare and fresh juices at Cafe Gratitude in less than 1 block. A few steps away, Osteria Mamma is the delicious Italian eatery and wine bar you're seeking for a romantic dinner.

*WHAT TO EXPECT FROM A PROPERTY MANAGED BY TURNKEY VACATION RENTALS*

TurnKey Vacation Rentals is a leading full-service property management company. We guarantee all listing information is accurate and up to date. From the moment you book, you’ll be provided timely and helpful communications regarding your trip. Upon arrival, easily access your unit with a keyless secure door code; no need for an in-person key exchange.

---

You can see that the detail subjects are fully capitalized.  My inclination is to build a custom pipe, that detects fully capitalized words.  However, the subjects aren't just one word, but often many.  And even after detecting them, how would I style the DOM from a pipe to format the text?

Am I overcomplicating this?  Is there something obvious I am missing?  I ask because this seems like it would be a pretty common problem with abstracted solutions.  Any suggestions on a modern way to do this?

Any help much appreciated.  **Thanks for taking a look**...

Comment: You can try using the `<pre></pre>` element

Comment: split your data using regex then you can easily differentiate between subjects and details

Answer (score 1):

After attempting this with a pipe, it became clear that it probably wasn't going to work. [But I was able to get it to work using another method](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-string-style). I'll come back through and explain what is going on in a bit (I need a break) but here is some food for thought.

## Your Challenges

- Finding the Headers - Actually finding them could be done with regex, but you'll run into some problems with the fact that some paragraphs start with A, which ends up getting tagged in something as simple as `(([A-Z]{1,} ){1,})`. *This is something you can account for*, but I opted out of that method originally. In hindsight (20/20, you know) it could end up using less code if you go that route.
- Styling your headers

  - Because it's just a string of text, you are basically required add in HTML inside the string *unless you separate the body and text and utilize* `ngFor` *and* `ngIf` *in some (complex) manner*.
  - If you decide to add HTML to the text (as I did), you will need to create an *empty element* that will contain your text and then change it's `innerHTML` to be the final text.
  - By doing that, you are submitting yourself to using in-line styling **or set** `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` **in the Component decorator**. Doing so means that Angular doesn't use the Shadow DOM on the component, [which you can read more about here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your text getting in same format that showed in ideally then you can just use p tag and apply css to p tag is `white-space: pre-wrap;`